# loading multiple images from document directory using concurrent queue, but UI is still blocking

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I was trying to load 6 images to 6 imageViews from document directory. I have used dispatchqueue

```
  let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myConcurrentQueue", qos: .background, attributes: [.concurrent,.initiallyInactive], autoreleaseFrequency: .inherit, target: nil)
```

But even i am using concurrent queue UI is still not responding, UI is blocked

I have used below code

```
 private func loadImagesConCurrent() {
    let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myConcurrentQueue", qos: .background, attributes: [.concurrent,.initiallyInactive], autoreleaseFrequency: .inherit, target: nil)
    dispatchq = concurrentQueue
    activity.startAnimating()
    for i in 0..<myArray.count {
        concurrentQueue.async { [weak self] in
            do {
                let location = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
                let filename = URL(fileURLWithPath: location!).appendingPathComponent((self?.myArray[i]) as! String)
                     
                if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filename.path) {
                      DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.imagesCollection[i].image = image
                        print("loaded")
                        if i == (self?.myArray.count)! - 1 {
                            self?.activity.startAnimating()
                        }
                      }
                    }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please help me midhun https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp

Comment: Is that loaded message getting printed ?

Comment: yes loaded message is printing, but UI is blocked, i have placed button, while tapping on the button its not responding, thanks

Comment: Your code looks fine, could you please comment out the code written inside the dispatch main and check whether the issue is there or not

Comment: Why `initiallyInactive`? Remove that option. Or `resume` it.

Comment: @Rob That's why I asked him whether his print statement worked or not, he said it's printing. So I hope he is calling activate from somewhere else.

Comment: i have removed self?.imagesCollection[i].image = image inside DispatchQueue.main.async it worked, i think as you said this is causing UI block.

Comment: @RintoAndrews What happens when you set the image property on that object ? Whether you wrote any didSet method to refresh the UI or are you doing anything when the image was set ?

Comment: self?.imagesCollection is outlet collection of images, i directly set image to the imageview

Comment: @MidhunMP - Yep, but my question to Rinto still stands. Why would one create a queue that’s not started? Seems convoluted to me. Generally you’d just do `let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myConcurrentQueue", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)` and you’re off to the races.

Comment: @Rob i have activated after calling the above method
if let queue = dispatchq {
            queue.activate()
  }

Comment: Yes, I gathered that you must be doing something like that if you saw the `print` statement (though I don’t believe that’s the actual syntax you used ... that’s syntactically incorrect), but I was wondering _why_ you’re doing it that way. Maybe you have some compelling reason, but if not, it’s just feels a bit unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: I have removed it, and I tried using only .concurrent, I am got same result,thanks

Comment: @Rob Yeah, you are right. There is no need to set `initiallyInactive` on this scenario.

Comment: @RintoAndrews Is anything overlapping your button after setting the images ? Is there any constraints error in your console ? Check your layout hierarchy before and after setting the images. I think the issue is nothing related to the above code.

Comment: Sure, I will check that,thanks

Comment: Rinto, by the way, how many of these images are there? Unbridled concurrent queue usage can exhaust the very limited number of GCD worker threads (which can cause deadlocks or random blocking). Admittedly, that only happens when you hit 64 concurrent requests (which I assume is unlikely in this case), but just sayin that unbridled concurrency is a bad thing. If using GCD, I’d do `concurrentPerform`. Or do the non-zero semaphore trick. Or I’d use `OperationQueue` with some reasonable `maxConcurrentOperationCount`. But we generally want to constrain concurrency to something reasonable.

Comment: There are 6 images only

Comment: By the way, and likely unrelated to your issue, but that `if i == (self?.myArray.count)! - 1 { ... }` pattern is incorrect. With concurrent tasks, you have no assurances about the order in which they will complete. We would generally use dispatch groups for this. E.g. https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/3fa777b853e0c5590d8815b2f313c99c

Comment: @MidhunMP, no other control overlapping the button, all images with size 1MB, does it cause the UI block?

Comment: I have downsized the image while loading, it gives more performance,
https://gist.github.com/rintoandrews90/37ed0b80e49699f9f1b3f7a761a000f6

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the UI is blocked because of below UI operation in concurrentQueue

```
activity.startAnimating()
```

This is an UI activity and probably you might be getting exception or backtrace mentioning that UI operations must be done in main thread. Try removing / moving activity.startAnimating() in main thread. The UI may not block and behave as you expected.

Even tough you have used concurrentQueue the UI image loading is done in main thread with DispatchQueue.main.async this should be Ok.

Comment: i have tried without activity.startAnimating(), but didnt work, this is not the reason, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove `,.initiallyInactive`:

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myConcurrentQueue", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .inherit, target: nil)
```

There's no reason this queue should use this option, and since it appears you never call `dispatch_activate()`, the queue will never execute any blocks.

Note: This is a *very* obscure queue option and, as a rule, you shouldn't use it unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: I thought same, but he is saying that his print statement is working. So somewhere else he is calling that activate

Comment: If the `print("loaded")` statement is executing then this code is not what's blocking the main thread or UI. My next suggestion would be to simply run the app and when it stalls, mash the "pause" button in the debugger and see what the main thread is doing. One thing to consider: I vaguely remember that images are loaded/decoded lazily, so it might be that the heavy lifting for the image loads isn't happening until the views are updated.

Comment: Following up on that thought, the code in [Asynchronously Loading Images into Table and Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/asynchronously_loading_images_into_table_and_collection_views) goes to the trouble of first reading the data in the URL, and *then* creating the image from that data (rather than just `UImage(contentsOfFile :url)`, which reinforces the idea that creating an image object from an URL is a lightweight/lazy operation.

Comment: all images with size of 1mb, does it matter? @JamesBucanek

Comment: @JamesBucanek i tried the above suggestion, that gives same result. thanks

Comment: i have downsized of image while loading it helps

Comment: Again, this would indicate that the UI/main thread is blocking while decoding/rendering the image data. Try profiling the code and see if that provides insight into were the app is spending its time, then work up the call chain to find out from whence. (tip: going back to the larger images will make it easier to spot the bottleneck.)